# Thread safe queue with refilling

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not sure if my proxy is fully thread safe. 
I don't want to use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of `LinkedList`, because I have to make sure the queue is not empty, so getProxy() is already synchronized.

"obtainProxy()" function is accessed by a few threads.

Is it enough to make it thread safe? Is this approach correct?

```
private static final Queue<Proxy> PROXIES = new LinkedList();

public static Proxy obtainProxy() {
    boolean isProxyOk = false;
    Proxy proxy = null;
    do {
        proxy = getProxy();
        isProxyOk = testProxy(proxy);
    } while (!isProxyOk);
    return proxy;
}

private synchronized static Proxy getProxy() {
    if(PROXIES.isEmpty()) prepareProxies();
    return PROXIES.poll();
}

private static void prepareProxies() {
    PROXIES.add(new Proxy());
    PROXIES.add(new Proxy());
    PROXIES.add(new Proxy());
}
```

EDIT: My goal is having a queue that provides a Proxy item for each thread that asked for it.

Comment: Well, you have a public unsynchronized method modifying shared state, so no, that's not thread-safe. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet prepareProxies() is private, that was a mistake, my apologies. How about now?

Comment: Now it's OK, but I still don't undrstand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet Explained a bit in edit

Comment: And why use a queue? Why do you even need state? Why don't you just create a proxy (whatever that is) every time someone asks for one?

Comment: I have a large proxy base and I want threads to have unique proxy, so I thought it was a good idea. As I think now, I can just use a list and increment index variable after each access. Thank you for your time though